# How to mock a function for a specific test if its already mocked in parent?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Lets suppose i have the following code and i mocked it in parent scope, now i want to mock it in the test specific scope which means i want to change its mocked value in a specific test case so how i can do it?

```
jest.mock('../../hooks/any-hook', () => ({
  useCreateMutation: () => ({
    mutate: jest.fn(),
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
  })
}));
```

i mocked it in parent so how i can re-mock it in a specific test case for to update its value?

I used jest.doMock but not working in the test specific scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your mocked module return a mock function for `useCreateMutation`, then you can use one of the following mock return functions on it to modify its behavior in a specific test:

- [mockFn.mockReturnValueOnce(value)](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvalueoncevalue)
- [mockFn.mockImplementationOnce(fn)](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn)

```
jest.mock('../../hooks/any-hook', () => ({
  useCreateMutation: jest.fn(() => ({
    mutate: jest.fn(),
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
  })),
}));
```

This test just uses the normal mock specified in the `jest.mock()` call above:

```
test('uses the default mock', () => {
  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useCreateMutation();

  expect(isLoading).toBe(false);
  expect(isSuccess).toBe(false);
});
```

And then you would override a mock customized for a specific test:

```
test('uses the specified mock', () => {
  jest.mocked(useCreateMutation).mockReturnValueOnce({
    mutate: jest.fn(),
    isLoading: true,
    isSuccess: true,
  });

  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useCreateMutation();

  expect(isLoading).toBe(true);
  expect(isSuccess).toBe(true);
});
```

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/so-76096131-5kby1q) which puts it all together.

There are also [`mockResolvedValueOnce()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue)/[`mockRejectedValueOnce()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvalueoncevalue) functions for mocking Promises.

All of these can be used multiple times to return a different value each time the mocked function is called.